# Navigation in react native router flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have this configuration of the routers in my app --

```
<Router navigationBarStyle={styles.navBar}
                titleStyle={styles.navBarTitle}
            >
                <Scene key="modal" component={Modal}>
                    <Scene key="drawer" component={Drawer} open={false} type="replace" initial={this.state.flag ? false : true}>

                        <Scene key="mywishlist" component={MyWishlist} title="WISHLIST" type="replace" />
                        <Scene key="faq" component={FAQ} title="FAQ" type="replace" />
                        <Scene key="profilepic" component={ProfilePic} />
                        <Scene key="changepassword" component={ChangePassword} panHandlers={null} />
                        <Scene key="addressmanage" component={AddressManage} />
                        <Scene key="dishsearch" component={DishSearch} />
                        <Scene key="feedback" component={Feedback} hideNavBar type="replace" />
                        <Scene key="logout" component={Logout} hideNavBar type="replace" />
                    </Scene>
                    <Scene key="auth" initial={this.state.flag ? true : false} >
                        <Scene key="login" panHandlers={null} component={Login} title="Login" hideNavBar={true} type="replace" />
                        <Scene key="otp" panHandlers={null} component={OTP} title="OTP" hideNavBar={true} />
                        <Scene key="signup" panHandlers={null} component={SignUp} title="SignUp" hideNavBar={true} type="replace" />

                        <Scene key="coachmark" component={Coachmark} hideNavBar />
                    </Scene>
                    <Scene key="popUpImagePicker" panHandlers={null} component={PopUpImagePicker} title="PopUpImagePicker" hideNavBar={true} />
                    <Scene key="appModal" component={AppModal} />
                </Scene>

            </Router >
```

As soon as I come in logout I call `Actions.auth()` in my `componentWillMount()` to come to login screen but it is not working. Any suggestions on why not working and how can I route to login from any screen inside "drawer"?

Comment: hi... can you show more code in component `logout` ?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by not working? Is it a routing problem? In my project, I put a `TouchableOpacity` then if it is `onPress`, it will trigger logout service that using `AsyncStorage` to multiget and multiremove all info from user. And then to go back again into login page I use `Actions.login({ type: 'reset' });` to reset history like a discussion in this [link](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/512).